# How to automatically reflect changes when adding PHP cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

My website by default is in English

But I can change the language, when a visitor visits our website with a url of a news item in Spanish:

```
example.com/es/news/718/url-title-article/
```

The url given as an example is a news in Spanish since the first folder or directory is named "es" `example.com/es/news/718/url-title-article/` -> `es`

And, that's where the trick comes, since I have a function that allows me to obtain the name of the first folder or directory and if it matches with the given parameters, it should set a cookie with the language of that url, in this case Spanish -> "es".

```
if($FOLDER_LANG === "es" || $SUBDOMAIN_LANG === "es") {
    setcookie ('language', 'es', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'example.com');
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
    if($_COOKIE['language']==='en'){
        $WEBSITE_TITLE = " | WebSIte EN";
        $LANG = 'en';
        $language = "en";
    }elseif($_COOKIE['language']==='es'){
        $WEBSITE_TITLE = " | WebSite ES";
        $LANG = 'es';
        $language = "es";
    }
} else {
    $WEBSITE_TITLE = " | WebSite DEFAULT EN";
    $LANG = 'en';
    $language = "en";
}
```

But the problem, is that I have to reload the page to see the changes of the new language added to the site.

So how can you solve it without having to reload the site.

Comment: Set the language cookie after the reading the existing language code and set the language code to the new value before anything else starts on the site. You won't have to refresh that way.

Comment: @OnimushaI don't understand: / could you give me an example please :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the logic which determines the language so it doesn't *depend* on the cookie.

So, before, where you might have had something like:

```
$language_data = get_i18n_data( $_COOKIES['language'] );
```

You would instead have something like:

```
function get_language() {

    if($FOLDER_LANG === "es" || $SUBDOMAIN_LANG === "es") {
        setcookie ('language', 'es', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'example.com');
        return 'es'
    }

    return $_COOKIES['language'];
}

$language_data = get_i18n_data( get_language() );
```

Comment: Hi, add other details because the code provided still doesn't work: / I have to reload the page anyway to see the changes: /

Comment: Your structure needs work. I think that should be addressed first or you will run into more issues other than just this. The solution above is generic and solves the problem you posted. Other issues are a different matter and you most likely need professional assistance as it's not a coding issue but the core foundation looks problematic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for refresh being needed is that $LANG and $language is set by an existing cookie and not the new one.

Analysing your code:

```
if($FOLDER_LANG === "es" || $SUBDOMAIN_LANG === "es") {
    setcookie ('language', 'es', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'example.com');
}
```

Here, it's setting the cookie only in the header. It is not accessible until the page is reloaded.

One option is to add the following in the `if` condition:

```
$LANG = 'es';
$language = "es";
```

The rest of your code then reads existing cookies so this is what will load on the same page even if the cookie is set just before it:

A better way in my opinion is to keep it simple and expandable by using variable `$language` to drive the data:

```
$language = 'en'; //this is default
if(isset($_COOKIE['language'])){
    $language = $_COOKIE['language'];
}

//now check if current $language is different to folder
if($FOLDER_LANG != $language || $SUBDOMAIN_LANG != $language) {
    //this is condition depends on your variables. You might need && if both conditions should be met or modify as required
    //set the language for this page (so no need for refresh and also set the cookie
    $language = $FOLDER_LANG ? $FOLDER_LANG : $SUBDOMAIN_LANG; //sets to folder or sudomain language code if $FOLDER_LANG is empty. You can switch the two folders to priotorise the latter.
    //now set the cookie
    setcookie ('language', $language, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'example.com');
}

//now set the the title and the extra variable $LANG (you probably should choose one variable to use)
$WEBSITE_TITLE = " | WebSite  . strtoupper($language)";
$LANG = $language;
```

Now you can support more languages and also won't need to refresh

Comment: Your solution will not affect with this other problem you presented:  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384737/error-the-language-is-not-changed-when-i-am-in-a-url-with-different-folders-or-d?noredirect=1#comment115600309_65384737